# Hibernate Search Restricting Results

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I've constructed a very basic hibernate search from the hibernate documentation. I'm having a difficult time restricting the results and would like a little advise pertaining to what I'm doing wrong.

Scenario

Lets say I'm using one entity with a description title like so

```
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
private String name;
```

with the following data added to the index

```
1. Dell Laptop
2. Dell Desktop
3. HP Desktop
```

My search looks like so,

```
    FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(sessionManager.getSession());
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Computer.class).get();
    Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("name").matching(keyword).createQuery();

    org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Computer.class);
```

Now everything functions well when you do a keyword search using the following,

```
Dell returns Dell Laptop, Dell Desktop
Desktop returns Dell, HP
```

However when you do a search like so, it doesn't restrict the results properly

```
Dell Desktop returns Dell Laptop, Dell Desktop, HP Desktop.
```

How would I restrict the results to only return a single match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dell Desktop" probably isn't a single term.  you should try searching it as a phrase.

```
Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.phrase().onField("name").sentence(keyword).createQuery();
org.hibernate.search.FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Computer.class);
```

You could also use a query parser as documented in the Hibernate Search documentation, [Chapter 5](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html/search-query.html), in Example 5.2